# How can I control the Recycle View by clicking on the date of the calendar view?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, calendarview

I'm new in android and also new in English sorry my bad English...
I have learned android course at the academy.
My sentence may be wrong because it is written through a translator. I hope you understand with a generous heart.

Here's what I want:

If I click 15 days in Calendar View, 
It is hoped that only the 15th day information will be shown in the Recyclerview. If I click on another date in calenderview, for example, 20 days, I hope that the 15th item will disappear and only the 20th item view will be displayed.

Here's what I'm trying to do.
When I click a date in a calendar view, I want to see the Item View corresponding to that date.

- package com.example.myapplication;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.SharedPreferences;
  import android.icu.util.Calendar;
  import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
  import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.CalendarView;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Date;

  public class Calender extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  // CalendarView myCalenderView;

  // TextView schedule1, schedule11;

  String a, b, c;

  static String data1;
  long Now;
  Date date;
  java.text.SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY_MM_dd");

  TextView datetext;

  Context mcontext;

  private String getTime() {
      Now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      date = new Date(Now);
      return mFormat.format(date);
  }


  private ArrayList<calenderArrayList> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

  private ArrayList<calenderArrayList> bArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


  SharedPreferences preferences;

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


  private static String TAG = "recyclerview_example";

  //private ArrayList<calenderArrayList> mArrayList;

  //ArrayList 선언

  calendarAdapter mAdapter = new calendarAdapter(this, mArrayList);
  //mAdapter 선언

  //  calendarAdapter bAdapter = new calendarAdapter(this, bArrayList);
  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


  private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

  private int count = 0;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);

      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnCreate()실행");


      SharedPreferences calender_load = getSharedPreferences("calender", MODE_PRIVATE);

      calender_load.getInt("save_size", 0);

      int calender_size = calender_load.getInt("save_size", 0);
      Log.d("시작시b사이즈1", "" + calender_size);
      Log.d("시작시b사이즈1", "" + bArrayList.size());
      Log.d("시작시m사이즈1", "" + mArrayList.size());
      if (calender_size != 0) {

          for (int i = 0; i < calender_size; i++) {


              calenderArrayList calender = new calenderArrayList(calender_load.getString("save_date" + i, ""), calender_load.getString("save_work" + i, ""), calender_load.getString("save_place" + i, ""), calender_load.getBoolean("save_box" + i, false));

              if (calender.number_exam.equals(data1)) {
                  Log.d("불러오기값", "" + calender_load.getString("save_date" + i, ""));

                  bArrayList.add(calender);
                  mArrayList.add(calender);
              }
              mAdapter = new calendarAdapter(this, mArrayList);

              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      } else if (calender_size == 0) {

          mAdapter = new calendarAdapter(this, mArrayList);
          mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }


      mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_exam);
      //recycler_view라는 id를 가진 recycler_view를 mRecyclerView로 지정해준다.

      mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), 1));


      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


      //RecyclerView 내에 Item view들의 크기를 측정하고 위치를 지정
      //언제 item view를 재사용해야하는지에 대한 정책을 결정하고 결정.

      //mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


      mAdapter = new calendarAdapter(this, mArrayList);
      //RecyclerView 내에 보여지는 view 들에 date set을 binding 시켜주는 역할.
      //binding? 데이터 끼리 묵어준다?

      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      //mRecyclerView의 Adapter를 mAdapter로 set한다.
      //set? 지정한다. 놓다. 위치하다.


      // myCalenderView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);


  }


  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onStart();
      //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnStart()실행");


      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnResume()실행");


  }


  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onResume();
      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      final CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
      calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

              data1 = year + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth;

              String a = data1 + dayOfMonth;
              Log.d("날짜", "" + a);
              ArrayList<calenderArrayList> dayofMonth = new ArrayList<>();

              Log.d("어떤 이름으로?", "" + dayofMonth);
              if (dayofMonth.size() != 0) {

                  SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences("" + data1, MODE_PRIVATE);


              }

             /* if(mArrayList.size()!=0) {
                  for (int i=0; i<mArrayList.size() ; i++) {
                      SharedPreferences save11 = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE );
                      SharedPreferences.Editor save_editor = save11.edit();

                      save_editor.putBoolean("save_box"+i+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam, mArrayList.get(i).selected );
                      save_editor.putString("save_date"+i+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam, mArrayList.get(i).number_exam);

                      save_editor.putString("save_work"+i+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam, mArrayList.get(i).content_exam);

                      save_editor.putString("save_place"+i+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam, mArrayList.get(i).content_exam2);

                      save_editor.putInt("save_size"+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam, mArrayList.size());

                      save_editor.commit();


                  }
              }
              mArrayList.clear();

              if(mArrayList.size()!=0)
              {
                  for (int i =0; i<mArrayList.size(); i++){

                      if(mArrayList.get(i).number_exam.equals(data1)){


                      }

                  }
              }*/


              //int a = dayOfMonth;
              Toast.makeText(Calender.this, year + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              Log.d("리사이클러뷰 실행 전", "실행 전");
              mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_exam);
              Log.d("리사이클러뷰 실행 후", "실행 후");


              final EditText number_exam = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_date);
              final EditText content_exam = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_place);
              final EditText content_exam2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_content);

              //TextView ee = findViewById(R.id.number_exam);

              Log.d("사이즈 측정  실행 전", "실행 전");


              ArrayList<calenderArrayList> calenderArrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
              Log.d("실행11111", mAdapter.getItemCount() + "");

              Log.d("뭐가 들어있나?", "" + mArrayList);
              Log.d("뭐가 들어있나?", "" + mArrayList.size());
              // Log.d("뭐가 들어았나?", ""+mArrayList.get(1).number_exam.toString());
              //  Log.d("뭐가 들어았나?", ""+mArrayList.get(2).number_exam.toString());
              // Log.d("뭐가 들어았나?", ""+mArrayList.get(3).number_exam.toString());

              if (mArrayList.size() != 0) {
                  Log.d("if구문 실행됨?", "" + mArrayList.size());

                  //1. 일단 뷰 자체를 초기화 해주어야함.
                  //2. 초기화 된 뷰에 다시 mArrayList에서 선정 된 정보를 다시 나타내주어야한다.


              /*  for(int i = 0; i<mArrayList.size(); i++){

                      Log.d("얼마?", ""+i);
                      Log.d("for 구문 작동?실행", "여기까진 접속?");
                      if(mArrayList.get(i).number_exam.toString().contains(a)){

                          Log.d("뭐가 들어있나? 실행여부", ""+mArrayList.get(i).number_exam.toString());





                          a = mArrayList.get(i).number_exam;

                          b = mArrayList.get(i).content_exam;

                          c = mArrayList.get(i).content_exam2;


                          //mArrayList.add(mArrayList.get(i));



                      }


                  }*/


              }

          }
      });


      Button buttonInsert_exam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exam_button);
      //button 클릭시 발생하는 이벤트를 나타낸다. 여기서는 입력하기 버튼 클릭시 발생하는 상황.

      buttonInsert_exam.setOnClickListener(
              new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calender.this);
                      View view = LayoutInflater.from(Calender.this)
                              .inflate(R.layout.activity_calender_edit_box, null, false);
                      builder.setView(view);
                      final Button ButtonSubmit_exam = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_dialog_submit_exam);
                      final EditText number_exam = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_date);
                      final EditText content_exam = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_place);
                      final EditText content_exam2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calender_content);
                      // final EditText editTextKorean = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_dialog_korean);

                      ButtonSubmit_exam.setText("입력하기");

                      number_exam.setText(data1);
                      final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                      dialog.show();

                      //dialog에 나타나는 입력하기 버튼을 눌렀을 때 발생하는 상황
                      ButtonSubmit_exam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(View v) {


                              String strID = number_exam.getText().toString();
                              String strID2 = content_exam.getText().toString();
                              String strID3 = content_exam2.getText().toString();
                              //number와 content view에 입력한 문자열을 strID, strID2에 담는다.

                              //String strKorean = editTextKorean.getText().toString();

                              calenderArrayList dict = new calenderArrayList(strID, strID2, strID3);

                              bArrayList.add(0, dict);
                              mArrayList.add(0, dict); //첫 줄에 삽입
                              //mArrayList.add(dict); //마지막 줄에 삽입
                              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //변경된 데이터를 화면에 반영

                              Log.d("b사이즈", "" + bArrayList.size());
                              Log.d("m사이즈", "" + mArrayList.size());

                              dialog.dismiss();
                              //dialog를 종료 시켜준다.
                          }
                      });


                  }


              });
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPause();
      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPause()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      SharedPreferences calendersave = getSharedPreferences("calender", MODE_PRIVATE);

      SharedPreferences.Editor calendersaveeditor = calendersave.edit();

      //calenderArrayList calenderArrayList = new calenderArrayList();

      if (bArrayList.size() != 0) {

          for (int i = 0; i < bArrayList.size(); i++) {


              calendersaveeditor.putBoolean("save_box" + i, bArrayList.get(i).selected);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_date" + i, bArrayList.get(i).number_exam);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_work" + i, bArrayList.get(i).content_exam);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_place" + i, bArrayList.get(i).content_exam2);

              calendersaveeditor.putInt("save_size", bArrayList.size());

              calendersaveeditor.commit();


              Log.d("종료시b사이즈", "" + bArrayList.size());
              Log.d("종료시m사이즈", "" + mArrayList.size());

          }

      } else if (bArrayList.size() == 0) {

          calendersaveeditor.clear();
          calendersaveeditor.commit();
      }

      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnPause()실행");
  }


  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onStop();
      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStop()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





      /*
      * if(mArrayList.size()!=0){

          for(int i = 0; i< mArrayList.size(); i++){



              calendersaveeditor.putBoolean("save_box"+i, mArrayList.get(i).selected);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_date"+i, mArrayList.get(i).number_exam);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_work"+i, mArrayList.get(i).content_exam);

              calendersaveeditor.putString("save_place"+i, mArrayList.get(i).content_exam2);

              calendersaveeditor.putInt("save_size", mArrayList.size());

              calendersaveeditor.commit();


          }

      }

      else if(mArrayList.size()==0){

          calendersaveeditor.clear();
          calendersaveeditor.commit();
      }
  ```

  */

  ```
      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnStop()실행");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestart() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onRestart();
      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onRestart()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnRestart()실행");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onDestroy();
      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      Log.d("스케쥴선택액티비티", "OnDestroy()실행");
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add new entry in your existing mArrayList as i am can see from your code you are adding all existing entries again but not new entry.

After that you need to set adapter again with new mArrayList only then you will be able to see new data in your recycler view.

Comment: I would like to thank you first for your kind answers.

If you have time, I would appreciate it if you can give me a simple example through my code.

Comment: I modified the post. I will also upload adapter and arraylist information as soon as necessary. Thank you once again for your kindness.